# How to properly remove subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout, size-classes

I have a simple scrollview with 5 subviews. My structure looks like this:

[image]

I'm using size classes to lay everything out the way I want, and it works great. At the bottom, there is a webview intended for when I receive JSON with youtube links. Unfortunately, there are not always youtube videos, and when this happens, I am left with a blank space where the video would be.

I would like to instead have the label in between the image view and web view to be at the bottom WITHOUT the empty space where the webview would be.

I have tried removing the webview from the scrollview when there are no youtube videos, but this appears to lock the scrolling. I also tried setting the frame of the webview to 0, but the blank space remains. Below are the constraints for my webview.

[image]

How should I deal with getting rid of the extra space when there are no videos to display?

Answer (score 0):

You are using auto-layout structure, so when updating your UI you have to update the constraints :
so attaching needed constraints with outlets :

```
IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *_leadingSpaceConstraint;
IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *_topSpaceConstraint;
IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *_buttomSpaceConstraint; 
...
```

when need update UI change constraints values :

```
_leadingSpaceConstraint = x;
_topSpaceConstraint = y;
_buttomSpaceConstraint = z
...
```

then call : `[self.view layoutIfNeeded];`